# Oracle IDE to visually create views?

Tags: oracle, ide, view

Oracle IDE to visually = wizard (not writing sql) create views? any names? (eg like toad)

SQL Server Management Studio = can create views visually for sql server what is same for oracle

Comment: Visually?  Closest I can think of is via an ODBC connection through MS Access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried [SQL Developer](http://www.oracle.com/technology/software/products/sql/index.html)?

Once installed and connected - try the following.

1) Right click on Views icon

2) New View

3) Click Advanced check box

4) Interface appears which allows you select tables, where clauses etc.

**EDIT:** Just thought I would point out that the above allows the use of a "wizard" type interface to create a view. Not sure if that meets your requirement of "Visual"

Answer (score 1):

Want a purley visual experience? Try [DeZign for Databases](http://datanamic.com/dezign/index.html) by Datanamic. I haven't purchased the tool, but after an initial evaluation I'm wanting it. It lets you drag and drop items onto a visual designer and then generates the DDL for you.

Answer (score -2):

A little late, by here's an online designer - [WWW SQL Designer](http://ondras.zarovi.cz/sql/demo/)

Its mainly for MySQL but nevertheless pretty useful